# how do you render HOCs in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I understand HOCs to a certain level in React. I'm just a bit confused how they are rendered. so lets say I have the following

```
export const authenticateUser = WrappedComponent => props => (
  props.authenticated ? <WrappedComponent {...props} /> : <div> Please log in to continue </div>
)
```

this is my HOC (above). I want to have a HOC that I wrap all my components in and if the user is authenticated (logged in) they can view that screen. if not, then I tell them to log in. very simple, no fancy auth stuff for now. will just be a prop boolean so I can get HOCs working

Im then struggling where do I call `authenticateUser`

I've imported it into my main file

and then assigned it to a const like so:

`const auth = authenticateUser(welcomeScreen)`

but i'm still not entirely how I render `auth`. Ive tried doing `{auth}` but that doesn't seem correct.

I'm also not entirely sure where I pass the `...props` into wrapped component. any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where do you need it, I would say that you may want to put it in App.tsx like this

```
return (
   ....
   <Auth />
   ....
)
```

Remember you are required to change `auth` to `Auth`

Comment: do you know how I would change the `authenticated` prop that I'm passing down so that I can use a computed property key instead. I'd like to use the same HOC but pass in a different property so that I can show different screens based on different auth levels

Comment: it really depends on the context, there is no general answer for this. But lemme give you an idea, for example you can pass `userRoles` like this `const auth = authenticateUser(userRoles)` so the HOC will pass the roles to lower level and in the lower level component you can use (just as an example) `props.admin ? <FeatureForAdminOnly /> : null` and `props.subscriber ? <FeatureForSubscribers /> : null`